# Kibana Conditional Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I am looking to do a conditional search in Kibana. I have multiple form _types with similar fields. I would like to return the results of one type only dependant on the what exists in the other. I can not make use of the _missing and _exists query tags as the field will not necessarily be empty, it might just contain a different value. An example follows of what I would like to achieve.

The two types are nmap and shodan. Example files can be accessed at the following addresses:

```
/test/nmap/1
/test/shodan/1
```

Both files contain multiple fields an example of which is given below:

> **`ip:`** 10.0.0.1 **`port:`** 22 **`state:`** open **`service:`** ssh

Now I would like to do a count of the number of ssh ports open. Some will only be in the nmap results, some in the shodan results and some in both. I obviously would like to only count one port per ip giving priority to nmap results(i.e. if nmap says the port is open and shodan says its closed I count the nmap result). Would this be possible with a DSL query, the only case of conditional query I have seen is with the _missing and _existing tags, or would I have to create a custom script.